# Match up the version of MySQL that AWS Aurora uses to a MySQL Docker image

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-aurora

I want to spin up a MySQL Docker container with the version of MySQL that matches closest to the AWS RDS version "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.08.1".

Would that be the MySQL image with the tag 5.7.20?

Is there someplace to look something like this up?

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Aurora documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.Versions.html):

> There isn't a one-to-one correspondence between community MySQL 5.6 or 5.7 versions and the Aurora MySQL 1.x and 2.x versions. To check which bug fixes and new features are in a particular Aurora MySQL release, see [Database engine updates for Amazon Aurora MySQL 2.0](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.20Updates.html) and [Database engine updates for Amazon Aurora MySQL 1.1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.11Updates.html). For a chronological list of new features and releases, see Document history. To check the minimum version required for a security-related fix, see [Security vulnerabilities fixed in Amazon Aurora MySQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.CVE_list.html).

I think you should feel comfortable using the latest `mysql:5.7` docker image. This ensures your client has all the security fixes.